# List of Clojure Compatible Java Virtual Machines

Tags: jvm, clojure

A community wiki to vote
**up** for "i have used this jvm with clojure without problems"
**down** "i have used this jvm with clojure and had problems"

Specifying the problems in the comments will help others to tell if the risk applies to them.

Answer (score 9):

Sun Java 6 hotspot JVM

Answer (score 3):

Apple Supplied JVM 1.6

Answer (score 2):

the **Iced Tea** JVM

Answer (score 1):

Apple Supplied JVM 1.5